# typed equals overriding in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, overriding, variable-assignment

This is a weird question I'm sure.  I want to be able to do something like this:

```
crazy_model = CrazyModel.new(some: "initialization", hashy: "options") 
tame_model  = TameModel.new (other: "init", hashy: "things")

tame_model = crazy_model
```

but then programatically decide how crazy_model attributes get assigned to tame_model.  In C++ one would override the assignment operator with a typed operand. Is there a sexy solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: There's no sexy (or any, for that matter) solution that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The closest i can think of is

```
crazy_model = CrazyModel.new(some: "initialization", hashy: "options") 
tame_model  = TameModel.new (other: "init", hashy: "things")

converted_model = crazy_model.to_tame_model


class CrazyModel
 def to_tame_model
   TameModel.new({
     #assign the attributes here
   })
 end
end
```